# Pytorch random tensor generation with one fix value and rest of random value

Tags: python, random, pytorch, tensor

In my testing dataset, I have to always include one specific image(image at position 0) in each batch but others values can be randomly selected. So I am making a tensor which will have 1st value 0 (for 1st image) and the rest of others can be anything other than 0. My code snippet is below.

```
a= torch.randperm(len(l-1)) #where l is total no of testing image in dataset, code output->tensor([10, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5])
b=torch.tensor([0]) # code output-> tensor([0])
c=torch.cat((b.view(1),a))# gives output as -> tensor([0, 10, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5]) and 0 is used twice so repeated test image
```

However, above approach can include 0 twice as *torch.randperm* many times includes 0. Is there a way in torch to generate random number skipping one specific value. Or if you think another approach will be better please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just remove these 0s using conditional indexing (also assumed you meant `len(l) - 1`):

```
a= torch.randperm(len(l)-1) #where l is total no of testing image in dataset, code output->tensor([10, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5])
a=a[a!=0]
b=torch.tensor([0]) # code output-> tensor([0])
c=torch.cat((b,a))# gives output as -> tensor([0, 10, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5]) and 0 is used twice so repeated test image
```

Or if you want to make sure it's never put in:

```
a=torch.arange(1,len(l)) 
a=a[torch.randperm(a.shape[0])]
b=torch.tensor([0]) 
c=torch.cat((b,a))
```

The second approach is a bit more versatile as you can have whatever values you'd like in your initial a declaration as well as replacement.

Comment: Glad to hear, would you mind approving this answer to help anyone else looking for this question?

Comment: Tried, but since  I have less than 15 reputation, my upvotes are not counted right now. But approved it :)